# Splitting String using CharacterSet

Tags: swift, string, swift3

In Swift 2.x I was able to do:

```
let str = "Line 1\nLine 2\r\nLine 3\n"
let newlineChars = NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet()
let lines = str.utf16.split { newlineChars.characterIsMember($0) }.flatMap(String.init)
```

But in Swift 3.x it has changed. Can someone tell me how to use this in Swift 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer given by @jjatie is correct but it will also include empty `String` elements in an `Array`, you can simply remove empty String elements using `filter`.

```
let str = "Line 1\nLine 2\r\nLine 3\n"
let lines = str.components(separatedBy: .newlines).filter { !$0.isEmpty }
print(lines)
```

Answer (score 6):

This is a bit simpler in Swift 3 now.

```
let str = "Line 1\nLine 2\r\nLine 3\n"
let newlineChars = NSCharacterSet.newlines
let lines = str.components(separatedBy: newlineChars)
    .filter{ !$0.isEmpty }
```

or simply

```
let str = "Line 1\nLine 2\r\nLine 3\n"
let lines = str.components(separatedBy: .newlines)
    .filter{ !$0.isEmpty }
```